# How to fit content of a DIV with fixed height

Tags: javascript, css, layout, html

Consider that we have a DIV with fixed height. Without a defined `width`, the content will spread to the width of 100%. How to adjust the width to fill the DIV. Definitely, it is not posible with CSS, thus, I am looking for a solution with Javascript.

In this [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/yDPbh/), the text is spread across the width of 100% and leaves lots fo empty space in the fixed height. I need to set a width of 130px by javascript to fit the content to the entire DIV. But how to calculate the width?

**NOTE:** This value (130px) was estimated for the example text. Depending on the DIV content, javascript needs to calculate the width required to fit the content within the DIV.

Is there any way to estimate the 2D size of a DIV content?

CSS actually does this for height; when we have a fixed width, it continues the height to fill the DIV. Is it possible to do so for width too?

**Clarification:** How to vertically fill the DIV without knowing the width (we have a fixed height)?

Comment: if you are setting the width to 130px, why would you need to calculate the width? do you mean height

Comment: @DanielHunter the contents are variable! We do not know the length of content inside DIV. We need to set the width dynamically.

Comment: will the contents be an image then? if it is text it will fill what you tell it too.

Comment: So what would you want to do if the content fits in one line of 100% width? And what if it fits in one line of 101% width? Make two lines with 50.5% width? Basically, your problem is that you don't have *any* of the two dimensions fixed so there are "infinite" possible boxes with the requisite area.

Comment: We have height. if the content is more than possible width it will overflow the DIV (we can hide it). The problem is for when the content is fitable inside the DIV.

Comment: are you trying to make one line of text? or is this content an image

Comment: @DanielHunter one line? this is what CSS naturally does. We need to entirely fill the DIV height. That's it. How to vertically fill the DIV without knowing the width.

Comment: fill it with WHAT ALI text or an image

Comment: So you want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/KJAsz/)?

Comment: you can get the height and width of a div using jquery - http://jsfiddle.net/bJ7HB/6/

Comment: @DanielHunter we do not know the width to get it! we want to set it depending on the content, which can be text or image. It's a normal DIV with content.

Comment: i think i got it to scale the way you want see my updated answer with jsfiddle.. uses jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an alternate approach.. While less efficient, it may be more accurate than my other answer.

see example [here:](http://jsfiddle.net/bJ7HB/39/)

Basically loop the width down until the desired height is reached

```
<div id="AA">
    <div id='A'>
        I dont know how wide i am, I dont know how wide i am, I dont know how wide i am, I dont know how wide i am, I dont know how wide i need to be
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#AA {
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
}

#A {
   display: inline;
}
```

The Script:

```
    height = $('#AA').height();
minWidth = 300;

currentWidth = $('#A').width();
currentHeight = $('#A').height();
stop = false;

if (currentWidth >= minWidth) {

    while (stop === false) {
        if (currentWidth >= minWidth) {
            newWidth = currentWidth - 1;
            $('#AA').width(newWidth);
            currentHeight = $('#A').height();
            currentWidth = $('#A').width();
            if (currentHeight < height) {
                stop = false;
            }
            else {
                stop = true;
            }
        }
        else {
            stop = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you can do this using Javascript.

The trick is to use a helper `<div>` within which you let the browser flow the content to a specific width and see what height it comes up with. If the height of the helper `<div>` is more than that of the outer `<div>`, adjust the width to compensate.

Meanwhile, the outer `<div>` has `overflow: hidden` so all those flowing experiments don't produce jarring changes to your page layout.

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/TghkD/)**.

Comment: Well this is a tricky approach, but it can solve the problem! In fact, we need to define a minimum width.

Comment: @Ali: The fiddle already uses a minimum width of 210px. It will become obvious if you start with less text inside `#helper`.